# Wordpress. Downloadable doc/pdf files by category on my page

Tags: wordpress

I have a question. I need to add a downloadable doc/pdf files to my page by category. Tell me what I can do? Doc files will be stored in the database? I can't understand how to realize it. Help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't store .doc and .pdf files in a database. Your files will be stored in the wp-content folder. Databases are to be used explicitly for storing website content in tables, such as posts, pages and plugin settings for example.

I'd highly recommend you look at some basic WordPress tutorials to understand how WordPress works before taking on something like this.

You can browse the plugin directory to look for a good file manager.

Here's an article that may help you - https://www.wpmayor.com/best-document-file-management-plugins-wordpress/

Google-fu is essential for solving very simply problems like this.